# Riemann $\xi$ function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

$\xi: \mathbb{C}-\{0,1\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, 
$\xi(s):=\int_1^\infty (t^{(1-s)/2}+t^{s/2})(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 t})\frac{dt}{t}+\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}$

How to show that the integral is holomorphic? I was already able to show that the integral exists for $\forall s\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is obvious that $\xi(s)$ is complex differentiable, $\xi'(s)=\int_1^\infty ((-\log t)/2)t^{(1-s)/2}+((\log t)/2)t^{s/2})(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 t})\frac{dt}{t}-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}+\frac{1}{s^2}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you please elaborate on how $\xi '(s)$ is the derivative, specifically, how to derive a function within an integral?